# Multiple Read more issue in css, how do i solve that?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a 'read more' content using css. I got a solution as to how do it online. But when am making multiple read more contents, there is a problem.

When clicking on the second 'read more' button, the 1st set of text contents opens up instead of the second set of contents. How do I solve that?

```css
article {
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
    position: relative;
    *zoom: 1;
}

article:before, article:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

article:after { clear: both }

article section:last-of-type {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}

section {
    -webkit-transition: .125s linear;
    -moz-transition: .125s linear;
    -ms-transition: .125s linear;
    -o-transition: .125s linear;
    transition: .125s linear;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    width: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

[for="read_more"] {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -3rem;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: .65rem;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset -1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

[for="read_more"]:hover {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
}

[for="read_more"] span:last-of-type {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ section {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
    width: 100%;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ figure { width: 100% }

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ [for="read_more"] span:first-of-type {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ [for="read_more"] span:last-of-type {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <article>
        <input type="checkbox" id="read_more" role="button">
        <label for="read_more" onclick=""><span>Read More</span><span>Hide</span></label>     
            <section>
            <p>Vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id </p>
            </section>    
         <section>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
         <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est</p>
      </section>
    </article>​
</div>

<div>
    <article>
        <input type="checkbox" id="read_more" role="button">
        <label for="read_more" onclick=""><span>Read More</span><span>Hide</span></label>     
            <section>
            <p>Vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id </p>
            </section>    
         <section>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
         <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est</p>
      </section>
    </article>​
</div>
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ckxjhe97/)

Comment: IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: got it, same solution from lmgonzalves too! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `id` and `for` attributes in `checkbox` and `label` elements respectively. Something like:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="read_more1" role="button"/>
<label for="read_more1" onclick=""><span>Read More</span><span>Hide</span></label>
```

And then in CSS code a possible selector could be `[for^="read_more"]` instead `[for="read_more"]`.

Check a [**demo here**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/ckxjhe97/2/).